# Pickling a string reference

Tags: python-2.7, pickle

I have to pickle a very large structure. Within this structure I have to update a string that is referenced many times in the structure.

Let's make it easier:

```
myStruct = [1, 'myStr', 2, 'myStr']
```

The program should update the 'myStr' with a new value simultaneously. 
To achive this I did a string reference class like this:

```
class StrReference(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.value = 'myStr'

myRefStr = StrReference()     
myStruct = [1, myRefStr, 2, myRefStr]
```

Now I can update `myRefStr.value = 'newStr'`

I need to pickle `myStruct` object so that `StrReference` class gets pickled as a string.

```
[1, 'myStr', 2, 'myStr']
[1, 'newStr', 2, 'newStr']
```

I did try with `__getstate__` and `__reduce__` but without luck.
The pickled result will always reference `StrReference` class.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Actually the point is: I need StrReference class to be pickled as a simple string.

Comment: ...or I need any other way to update those strings at once in my big structure

Answer (score 0):

Use `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`

> **getstate**(self)
>
> Instead of the object's **dict** attribute being stored, you can return a custom state to be stored when the object is
>   pickled. That state will be used by **setstate** when the object is
>   unpickled.
>
> **setstate**(self, state)
>
> When the object is unpickled, if **setstate** is defined the object's state will be passed to it instead of directly applied to the object's **dict**. This goes hand
>   in hand with **getstate**: when both are defined, you can represent
>   the object's pickled state however you want with whatever you want.

See http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html#pickling and https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#pickling-and-unpickling-normal-class-instances

Comment: I already did it, but the pickled object will remain StrReference and not a string. I need that, once unpickled, the structure contains strings.

Comment: def __getstate__(self): return self.value

Comment: def __reduce__(self): retrun (string.__class, (self.value,))

Comment: I didn't implement __setstate__ because the process that will unpickle doesn't know about StrReference. It need to unpickle a simple string object. That's the point! :-/